Wave effect spills outside the frame in Sony Vegas Pro 13

I'm using the wave effect on a foreground element but it spills outside the frame and onto the black bar on the side. This is not visible in Vegas' preview but it appears as soon as I render the video. This problem occurs when I render the video in both 1080p and 720p.
I tried different aspect ratios and added a mask to crop the waves but it didn't work. Is there any way to crop the excess waves or remove the bars entirely?
